# Setup agenda jobs every monday

Tags: node.js, job-scheduling, agenda

I want to run a job on every Monday once.

I tried

```
agenda.every('* * * * * 1', 'Weekly keyworker report');
```

But it executes a every seconds.I am confused to use that. 
I am working based on [this package](https://github.com/agenda/agenda#versions--091).

Answer (score 2):

Unlike UNIX cron, [node-cron](https://github.com/kelektiv/node-cron) supports seconds and has six fields instead of five.

`* * * * * 1` means every seconds on Monday.

You have to change it to something like this:
`00 30 10 * * 1` which means every Monday at 10h30.